# What is the difference between calling chai-as-promised with or without a notify method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm using `chai` and `chai-as-promised` to test some asynchronous JS code.

I just want to check that a function returning a promise will eventually return an Array and wrote the 2 following tests:

**A**:

```
it('should return an array', () => {
    foo.bar().should.eventually.to.be.a('array')
})
```

**B**:

```
it('should return an array', (done) => {
    foo.bar().should.eventually.to.be.a('array').notify(done)
})
```

Both are passing OK, but only the **B** option actually runs the full code included in my bar() function (ie displaying the `console.log()` message from the code below). Am I doing something wrong? Why is that so?

```
bar() {
    return myPromise()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Doing stuff')
      return result.body.Data
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.err(e)
    })
  }
```

Comment: If you're using Mocha (or another test framework that supports promises), there's a third option: `it(..., () => { return foo.bar().should.eventually... })` (because `eventually` returns a promise, and when a test case returns a promise, Mocha will handle it properly without the need for a callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What test library do you use? [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises), Intern or other?
For Mocha and Intern, you must return the promise from your test method:

```
it('should return an array', () => {
    return foo.bar().should.eventually.to.be.a('array');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing a promise means that you’re testing asynchronous code. Notify and done callback sets up a timer and waits for the promise chain to finish up executing.

The second approach is the correct one since you may need to test chained promises.

Take a look at this [tutorial](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/08/17/asynchronous-unit-tests-with-mocha-promises-and-winjs/) which got me into asynchronous unit testing.